# Get an instance of TypeScript class?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I have some legacy code I want to start unit-testing. It's a class like this:

```
export class Controller {
    private something: any;

    constructor() { this.something = true; }

    public getSomething(): any { return this.something; }
}
```

Trying to unit-test it with Mocha like this:

```
import Controller from '../../src/Controller';

describe('Controller', () => {
    let subject: any;

    beforeEach( () => {
        subject = new Controller(); // compiler complains here
    });

    describe('getOptions()', () => {
        it('should get something', () => {
            let result: any = subject.getOptions();
            if (typeof result !== 'object') {
                throw new Error('Expected object but got ' + result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Compiler complains:

> [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature.

How do I get an instance of the `Controller` class to run tests against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to import the **Controller** as a default export while it isn't.

Try:

```
import {Controller} from '../../src/Controller';
```

or:

```
export default class Controller {
```

You can read more about imports in general on the MDN page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Excellent, first option works! Where can I read up on the difference between a default and a non-default export?

Comment: @montrealist I added a link to the answer for future reference. :)